# Why do shared_ptr deleters have to be CopyConstructible?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, shared-ptr

In C++11 `std::shared_ptr` has four constructors which can be passed deleter objects `d` of type `D`. The signatures of these constructors are the following:

```
template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y * p, D d);
template<class Y, class D, class A> shared_ptr(Y * p, D d, A a);
template <class D> shared_ptr(nullptr_t p, D d);
template <class D, class A> shared_ptr(nullptr_t p, D d, A a);
```

The standard requires in [[util.smartptr.shared.const]](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.const#7) type `D` to be CopyConstructible. Why is this needed? If `shared_ptr` makes copies of `d` then which of these deleters might get called? Wouldn't it possible for a `shared_ptr` only to keep a single deleter around? What does it mean for a `shared_ptr` to *own* a deleter if `d` can be copied?

**What is the rationale behind the CopyConstructible requirement?**

PS: This requirement might complicate writing deleters for `shared_ptr`. `unique_ptr` seems to have much better requirements for its deleter.

Comment: If `d` is not copyConstructible, then how would the *shared_ptr's constructor* will store it as internal data to be used later?

Comment: @Nawaz: By movement.

Comment: I thought *move* is just an efficient version of *copy*.

Comment: @Nawaz: Conceptually, yes. But a type can be MoveConstructible and not CopyConstructible. Like `unique_ptr`. His question is essentially why `shared_ptr` forbids the use of a move-only Deleter type.

Comment: easier to implement thread safety? e.g. majority of members are copied so only the minority shared members need to be handled?

Comment: I have to wonder if they did this so that implementations could copy the deleter into a weak_ptr.  What makes we think this is the description of the return from `get_deleter`: *Returns: If p owns a deleter d of type cv-unqualified D, returns &d; otherwise returns 0. The returned
pointer remains valid as long as there exists a shared_ptr instance that owns d. [ Note: It is unspecified
whether the pointer remains valid longer than that. This can happen if the implementation doesn’t
destroy the deleter until all weak_ptr instances that share ownership with p have been destroyed.
—end note ]*

Comment: @Nawaz I would not think it is wise to say that move is a version of copy; with a copy, the source is still available. With a move, the source contents are no longer there (though the variable, if available, is still there, with undefined contents).

Comment: @NathanOliver get_deleter need you offer the type of deleter, so I think nullptr will returned if the type is wrong. And deleter for shared_ptr is also a part of state, weak_ptr should also hold it.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is that it was designed at a time when there was no move semantics. Right now I can't think of anything fundamentally problematic with a move-only deleter.

Comment: @T.C. As noted by Maxim in the comments of his answer, `shared_ptr` was first introduced in TR1. When it was moved from `std::tr1` to `std` for C++11, they added some support for move semantics. It is possible that the CopyConstructible requirement was left due to oversight.

Comment: Maybe caused by that deleter can be held by a `std::function` only if it is CopyConstructible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This question was perplexing enough that I emailed Peter Dimov (implementer of `boost::shared_ptr` and involved in standardization of `std::shared_ptr`)

Here's the gist of what he said (reprinted with his permission):

> > My guess is that the Deleter had to be CopyConstructible really only as a 
> >     relic of C++03 where move semantics didn’t exist.
>
> Your guess is correct. When `shared_ptr` was specified rvalue references
>   didn't exist yet. Nowadays we should be able to get by with requiring 
>   nothrow move-constructible.
>
> There is one subtlety in that when
>
> ```
> pi_ = new sp_counted_impl_pd<P, D>(p, d);
> ```
>
> throws, `d` must be left intact for the cleanup `d(p)` to work, but I
>   think that  this would not be a problem (although I haven't actually
>   tried to make the  implementation move-friendly).
>   [...] 
>   I think that there will be no problem for the 
>   implementation to define it so that when the `new` throws, `d` will be left 
>   in its original state.
>
> If we go further and allow `D` to have a throwing move constructor, things get 
>   more complicated. But we won't. :-)

Comment: I had been wondering this, and trying to find a reference for a while.  Kudos for just asking :)

Comment: This looks to me like a candidate for a standard change proposal. Why hasn't anyone proposed it yet? It's been 6 years since this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between deleters in `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` is that `shared_ptr` deleter is type-erased, while in `unique_ptr` deleter type is part of the template.

[Here is Stephan T. Lavavej explaining](https://youtu.be/zt7ThwVfap0?t=2478) how type erasure leads to CopyConstructible requirement in `std::function`.

As for the reason behind this difference in pointer types, it has been addressed on SO several times, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742290/deleter-type-in-unique-ptr-vs-shared-ptr).

A quote of what S.T.L. said:

> Very surprising "gotcha" I would say is that the `std::function` requires  CopyConstructible function objects, and this is kind of unusual in the STL.
>
> Usually the STL is lazy in the sense that it doesn't need things up front: if I have something like a `std::list` of type `T`, `T` does not need to be less-than-comparable; only if you call the member function `list<T>::sort` then it actually does need to be less-than-comparable.
>
> The core language rule that powers this is that the definitions of member functions of a class template are not instantiated until they're actually needed and the bodies don't exist in some sense until you actually call it.
>
> This is usually cool - this means you only pay for what you need, but `std::function` is special because of type erasure, because when you construct the `std::function` from some callable object `F` it needs to generate everything you could ever need from that object `F` because it's going to erase its type. It requires all the operations that it could possibly ever need regardless of if they're used.
>
> So if you construct a `std::function` from some callable object `F`, `F` is absolutely required at compile-time to be CopyConstructible. This is true even though `F` will be moved into the `std::function`, so even if you give it an r-value and even if you never copy `std::function`s anywhere in your program, `F` is still required to be CopyConstructible.
>
> You'll get a compiler error saying so - maybe horrible, maybe nice - depending on what you get.
>
> It just cannot store movable only function objects. This is a design limitation caused in part by the fact that `std::function` dates back to boost/TR1, before r-value references, and in some sense it can never be fixed with `std::function`'s interface as it stands.
>
> Alternatives are being investigated, maybe we can have a different "movable function", so we will probably get some sort of type-erased wrapper that can store movable only function in the future, but `std::function` as it stands in c++17 right now cannot do that, so just be aware.

Comment: @jotik I just added the whole quote that I extracted from YouTube closed captions, hopefully this is OK

Answer (score -2):

Because `shared_ptr` are meant to be copied, and any of those copy could have to delete the object, so they must all have access to a deleter. Keeping only one deleter would require, well, refcounting the deleter itself. If you really want that to happen, you could use a nested `std::shared_ptr` as the deleter, but that sounds a bit overkill.

Comment: But the deleter already is reference counted. Most implementations stick it in the control block with the pointer to be deleted. Copying a `shared_ptr` will not copy the deleter.

Comment: Is that certain (i.e. specified in the standard) ? In that case you would still need to copy in once to the refcounted chunk, but I stand corrected.

Comment: Not sure why you're being downvoted. It would be perfectly reasonable for an (albeit, naïve) implementation to do this.

Comment: No offense taken, they have a perfect point: it can be designed so only one copy is needed, and it could be a move. So while my answer is a potential explanation as to why it has to be copiable, it's quite inaccurate.

Comment: @NicolBolas, still, standard doesn't require deleter to be reference-counted. Which makes perfect sense why deleter has to be copy-constructible.

Comment: @AndreiR.: "*standard doesn't require deleter to be reference-counted.*" No, it doesn't. But the only way to implement `shared_ptr` where the deleter is not stored with the control block is to store it in a type-erased value type with every `shared_ptr`. And `weak_ptr`, for that matter. Why would you ever implement it like that? The main point is that Deleters are not required to be copy-constructible just to support stupid implementations of `shared_ptr`.