# Why is std::function itself a copy-constructible type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've found the tr.func.require section of the specification that requires `std::function` to be copy-constructable in C++11, and I've seen plenty of explanations of why this implies that the functors used to construct `std::function` have to be copyable, but why did the C++11 standard made `std::function` copyable in the first place, instead of making it a move-only type?

Comment: Probably because a lot(maybe all, can't remember) of the algorithms defined by the standard are allowed to copy the functor passed to them.

Comment: std::function should be usable like a C function pointer, otherwise it would be pretty useless. This means unrestricted cooying. If I want to store copies of a function at two different locations, how would I do that with move-only functions?

Comment: NathanOliver, is that requirement explicitly spelled out anywhere? Spot-checking, I'm not finding any such requirement documented in most of the algorithms, except (so far) the parallel version of for_each introduced in C++17.

Comment: we need `std::unique_function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function` was implemented before C++11 when move-semantics were not yet available (it stems from [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/function.html) and was part of [TR1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Function_objects)).

My guess is that `std::function` was specified (and perhaps voted into the standard) before move semantics. And the didn't have time to review all the rest of the standard in light of this. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500079/3919155) about [why shared_ptr deleters have to be CopyConstructible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36744238/3919155).

Also, for compatibility reasons, it sounds unreasonable to all-of-a-sudden make `std::function` move constructible and remove its copy-constructor.

Comment: Are you certain? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function suggests that std::function was introduced in C++11.

Comment: @PeterMilley: Yes, but the process of producing C++11 took ~4 years. `std::function` was added to C++11 first, then move semantics were added to C++11 later. They chose to "ship" C++11 rather than reviewing all the existing algorithms in detail.